# PHP based redirect script (geoplugin-based)

Tags: php

I have multiple versions of my website for different countries. So the 'www' sub-domain will host index.php page that will validate user's country and redirect them on the respective country's site. The main target are 6 countries they have respective sub-domain (ex, in.mydomain.com, us.mydomain.com, uk.mydomain.com, etc)

[image]

Now I want to put a condition here that if none of the above parametres are satisfied (No matching country code detected, or if user is not from any of these countries), they should be redirected to https://global.mydomain.com

How can I do this? Sorry, learning PHP.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Minimal, complete, verifiable example applies here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem, and whatever you have done or tried so far to solve the problem. **We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file** and reproduce your issue. Notably, we need you to include the entire error message, as well as enough data to get us to the problem point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `if-elseif` ladder instead of `if` condition every time. Then in last else put your code that executes when all condition become `false`

```
if(condition1)
{
//your redirection code
}
elseif(condition2)
{
//your redirection code
}
elseif(condition3)
{
//your redirection code
}
....
else
{
header("Location: https://global.mydomain.com");
 exit();
}
```

Comment: Seems like typing on mobile makes me  almost double your answer lol, good point tho!

Answer (score 0):

You could put it into a single if/else if/else statement.

Now your conditional structure consists of few if conditionals like so:

```
    if ($countrycode == 'en') {
        Do this
    }
    if ($countrycode == 'pl') {
        Do that
    }
```

Instead write a structure likewise:

```
   if ($countrycode == 'en') {
        Do this
    } elseif ( $countrycode == 'pl' ) {
        Do that
    } elseif ( $countrycode == 'fr' ) {
        Do 3rd
    } else {
        If none of above conditions is met do this line
    }
```